# In C#, what is the best/accepted way of doing constructor chaining?

Tags: c#, constructor, chaining

Given the following class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private string _param;

    public MyClass ()
    {
        _param = string.Empty;
    }

    public MyClass (string param)
    {
        _param = param;
    }
}
```

I am torn apart between two ways to chain those constructors:

**The first one**:

```
public MyClass () : this (string.Empty)
{
}

public MyClass (string param)
{
    _param = param;
}
```

**The second one:**

```
public MyClass ()
{
    _param = string.Empty;
}

public MyClass (string param) : this ()
{
    _param = param;
}
```

So, is it better to chain from the parameterless constructor or the other way around?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With your example, I'd go the first way. The second doesn't actually eliminate any code duplication that you are presumably trying to avoid, since you still have to explicitly set `_param`. The empty `this()` call in the second approach is completely gratuitous.

Comment: Indeed, and it seems to be the consensus here.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer the first. The behavior of the constructors will always be coherent and predictable that way, plus it reduces code duplication.

Answer (score 3):

Chain from pramater less to pramater,

so calling from lessor param constructors with default vals to more parameters

```
public MyClass()
{
    MyClass(default value here);
}

public Myclass(value)
{
    _value = value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd imagine that it's always better to chain from lesser to greater, i.e. why assign an empty string then a given string in the constructor when it makes more sense to pass the default (string.Empty) to the parameterised constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the first as well. Just as in a complex derived class inheriting from a simple base class, you want the "complex" constructor to build on the functionality of the "basic" one.

Answer (score 1):

Second example in your case really does not make sense, since you duplicate assignment of the class member (if you use `MyClass (string param)` constructor).

Second approach is more useful if chained constructors are "adding functionality".

Example:

```
public MyClass ()
{
    _param0 = string.Empty;
}

public MyClass (string param1) : this ()
{
    _param1 = param1;
}

public MyClass (string param1, string param2) : this (param1)
{
    _param2 = param2;
}
```

In your particular case, the first example is obviously much more appropriate, since you have only one assignment to the same member.

Answer (score 0):

If you state your goal here as "providing a default when no value is specified", then you should clearly use the first approach.

The general rule would then be: chain from least-specific constructor to most-specific.